# Class in observer is not triggered but the file runs (sales_order_invoice_save_after)

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, magento-1, create-invoice

I'm having a problem in a Magento Module. 
I'm trying to modify a module to add an observer that will do stuf only after the invoice is created and the order is paid (`sales_order_invoice_save_after`), and this is what the config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Datasource_Moloni>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Datasource_Moloni>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <moloni>
        <class>Datasource_Moloni_Helper</class>
      </moloni>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <moloni>
        <class>Datasource_Moloni_Block</class>
      </moloni>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <moloni>
            <class>Datasource_Moloni_Model</class>
        </moloni>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <observers>
                <moloni>
                    <class>moloni/auto</class>
                    <method>genInvoice</method>
                    <type>model</type>
                </moloni>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
    </events>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <moloni>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Datasource_Moloni</module>
          <frontName>moloni</frontName>
        </args>
      </moloni>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <moloni module="moloni">
        <title>Moloni</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <molonibackend module="moloni">
            <title>Moloni</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>moloni/adminhtml_molonibackend</action>
          </molonibackend>
        </children>
      </moloni>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <moloni translate="title" module="moloni">
              <title>Moloni</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
                  <molonibackend translate="title">
                    <title>Moloni</title>
                  </molonibackend>
              </children>
            </moloni>
          </children>
        </admin>
        <moloni_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </moloni_write>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <moloni>
          <file>moloni.xml</file>
        </moloni>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

It tries to run the script in the folder `includes/src` folder, where I have the file `Datasource_Moloni_Model_Observer.php` .

Inside that file, I have something like this:

```
<?php

class Datasource_Moloni_Model_Auto
{
public function genInvoice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    { 
         echo "inside the function";
    }
}

echo "outside";
```

The result no matter what is always "outside". 
I've tried changing the class so many times in the XML and the PHP files, that I don't know how many things I tried...

Anyone knows why this is happening or has any sugestion? Would love to ear some feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Echoing in files to test them is not ideal. Even more in observers as the way they are called is different than anything else.

I would recommend:

- **Enable the logs** in the backend
- **Replace your echo with `Mage::log("inside the function");` .** Also don't add echo outside of a class declaration, it won't help you debug it.
- Or even better, **use xdebug and add a breakpoint inside your function** to see if it's called.
- Also as you said "It tries to run the script in the folder includes/src folder" I would suggest you **disable the compiler under System > Tools > Compilation when developping your module.** Recompile and reenable once you're finished your development